# Back fill nulls with non null values in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, window-functions

I have a Spark data frame where I need to create a window partition column ("desired_output"). This column needs to back fill and non-null values.

I am looking to backfill the first non-null value and if a non-null does not exist, continue to persist that last non-null value forward.

Here are some use cases and their desired output:

```py
columns = ['user_id', 'date', 'date2', 'desired_outcome']
data = [\
        ('1','2022-01-01', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1','2022-01-02', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1','2022-01-03', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1','2022-01-04', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1','2022-01-05', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1','2022-01-06', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('1','2022-01-07', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2','2022-01-01', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2','2022-01-02', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2','2022-01-03', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2','2022-01-04', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2','2022-01-05', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05'),\
        ('2','2022-01-06', None, '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2','2022-01-07', None, '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2','2022-01-08', None, '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2','2022-01-09', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2','2022-01-10', None, '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2','2022-01-11', None, '2022-01-09'),\
        ('2','2022-01-12', None, '2022-01-09'),
        ('3','2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01'),\
        ('3','2022-01-02', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-03', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-04', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-05', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-06', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-07', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-08', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-09', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-10', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-11', None, '2022-01-05'),\
        ('3','2022-01-12', None, '2022-01-05')]

sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

I've tried to following solution but can't quite get the results to return as "desired_output" column.

```py
window = (
        Window
        .partitionBy('user_id')
        .orderBy('date')
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    )

sample_df = sample_df.withColumn('backfill', last('date2', ignorenulls=True).over(window))
```

Comment: what should be the output for user_id=1 and date='2022-01-06'? should it be null or user_id=2's non-null date2?

Comment: Good question. That's the weirdness of this use case. If there is only one non-null value in the partition (user_id), then that non-null value should populate all null values (before and after). Essentially what I am ultimately trying to do is count the time BEFORE, AFTER, BETWEEN the non-null values.

Comment: soooo, for the case where a partition has 2 dates, what happens in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it over 2 windows, one looking forward and returning the first non-null value, the other looking backwards and returning the last non-null value.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w_following = W.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(0, W.unboundedFollowing)
w_preceding = W.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, 0)
sample_df = sample_df.withColumn(
    'date3',
    F.coalesce(
        F.first('date2', True).over(w_following),
        F.last('date2', True).over(w_preceding)
    )
)
```

Result:

```py
sample_df.show(99)
# +-------+----------+----------+---------------+----------+
# |user_id|      date|     date2|desired_outcome|     date3|
# +-------+----------+----------+---------------+----------+
# |      1|2022-01-01|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      1|2022-01-02|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      1|2022-01-03|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      1|2022-01-04|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      1|2022-01-05|2022-01-05|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      1|2022-01-06|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      1|2022-01-07|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      2|2022-01-01|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      2|2022-01-02|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      2|2022-01-03|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      2|2022-01-04|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      2|2022-01-05|2022-01-05|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      2|2022-01-06|      null|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      2|2022-01-07|      null|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      2|2022-01-08|      null|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      2|2022-01-09|2022-01-09|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      2|2022-01-10|      null|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      2|2022-01-11|      null|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      2|2022-01-12|      null|     2022-01-09|2022-01-09|
# |      3|2022-01-01|2022-01-01|     2022-01-01|2022-01-01|
# |      3|2022-01-02|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-03|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-04|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-05|2022-01-05|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-06|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-07|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-08|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-09|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-10|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-11|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# |      3|2022-01-12|      null|     2022-01-05|2022-01-05|
# +-------+----------+----------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. So if I understand correctly you basically return 2 different values and merge into one column based on the first non-null value?

Comment: Yea, I think you understand it well